# How to find the date difference excluding weekends using PySpark without using UDF

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

Assume we have a dataframe as follows
`df = spark.createDataFrame([ ("2023-10-26",), ("2022-09-01",), ("2021-08-10",), ], ["start_date"]) df.show()`

i want to generate a new column with a new date obtained by subtracting or adding a specific days to those "start_date" in my df **while excluding the weekends(Assume Saturday and Sundays)** and this needs to be done without making use of the UDF.
In other words i am trying to replicate ["firstworkdate" function part of Qlik](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2023/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/firstworkdate.htm#) using PySpark

DBR version - 12.2 LTS,
Spark version - 3.3.2
Azure Databricks Environment

I know this can be done using UDF but i dont want to make use of UDF as its is not supported in Unity catalouge
Session specific UDF definition also does not work in my case

Comment: Are you using AWS or Azure databricks?

Comment: Azure Databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LOGIC:**

Here is a way to find the FirstWorkDay. Lets try with 2023-12-16 (Saturday) as End_Date and 10 as day_num:

1. Check if the End_Date is weekday or not. If it is a weekend then our End_Date should be the closest Friday, i.e 2023-12-15.
2. Get the date of the Monday that just passed, i.e 2023-12-11.
3. Get the diff between Recent_Monday and End_Date, i.e 5
4. Subtract day_num and diff = 10-5 = 5
5. Find the week difference between End_day and FirstWorkDay: ceil(Subtracted_days/5), i.e ceil(5/5) = 1
6. Find the number of days between End_day and FirstWorkDay: Subtracted_days + ceil_num*2 = 5 + 1*2 = 7
7. So we need to subtract 7 days from Recent_Monday to get our answer. 2023-12-11 - 7 days = 2023-12-04.

Note: We follow the above steps if the day_num > week_number (Mon: 0, Tue: 1, Wed: 2....). Else we can directly subtract day_num from End_Date.

**Implementation:**

```
def firstWorkDay(df, date_col, num_date_col):
"""
Purpose: Get the First Working Day, given an end date and number of working days to in between. 

Parameters: df -> Dataframe: The dataframe to be passed with date(end date) and num_date(number of working days) columns.
            date_col -> str: Name of the date(end date) column
            num_date_col -> str: Name of the num_date(number of working days) column

Returns: A dataframe with column "firstWorkDay" added
"""

df = calc_dayofweek_from_monday(df, date_col, "num_day")
# Check if the date is weekday or not. If it is a weekend then our new_date should be the closest Friday
df = df.withColumn(
    "new_date",
    when(
        date_format(date_col, "E").isin(["Sat", "Sun"]),
        date_sub(
            col(date_col), when(date_format(date_col, "E") == "Sat", 1).otherwise(2)
        ),
    ).otherwise(col(date_col)),
)
# Re-calculate the dayofweek for new_date
df = calc_dayofweek_from_monday(df, "new_date", "new_num_day")
df = df.withColumn(
    "nearest_monday", date_sub(col("new_date"), col("new_num_day") - 1)
)
df = df.withColumn("day_diff_from_mon", col(num_date_col) - col("new_num_day"))
# We would need to accomodate the day_diff_from_mon in weeks_req 
df = df.withColumn("weeks_req", (ceil(col("day_diff_from_mon") / 5)))
# Accounting the Sat, Sun present in a week so that we can directly subtract days_sub_till_mon days from nearest_monday and get the FirstWorkDay
df = df.withColumn(
    "days_sub_till_mon", col("day_diff_from_mon") + col("weeks_req") * 2
)
# We follow the above steps if the num_date_col > new_num_day (week_number (Mon: 0, Tue: 1, Wed: 2....)). Else we can directly subtract day_num from new_date
df = df.withColumn(
    "firstWorkDay",
    when(
        col(num_date_col) > col("new_num_day"),
        date_sub(
            col("nearest_monday"), col("days_sub_till_mon").cast(IntegerType())
        ),
    ).otherwise(
        date_sub(col("new_date"), col(num_date_col).cast(IntegerType()) - 1)
    ),
)

return df.select(date_col, num_date_col, "firstWorkDay")
```

Note: In my case, I needed the week to start on Monday hence I have created a custom function called "calc_dayofweek_from_monday" but default "dayofweek" can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following approach in PySpark:

- First, I imported the functions from PySpark. `col` is used to reference DataFrame columns, `date_add` is used to add days to a date, `dayofweek` is used to get the day of the week for a given date, and `when` is used for conditional expressions.
- I set the number of days to add to the original dates.
- I created a new column "**new_date**" by adding the specified number of days to the "**start_date**" column.
- I used `dayofweek` to determine if the resulting date falls on a weekend (1 represents Sunday and 7 represents Saturday).
- I used `when` and `otherwise` to adjust the "**new_date**" column by adding 2 days if it falls on a weekend.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_add, dayofweek, when
Dilip_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("2023-10-26",),
    ("2022-09-01",),
    ("2021-08-10",),
], ["start_date"])
days_to_add = 5
Dilip_df = Dilip_df.withColumn("new_date", date_add(col("start_date"), days_to_add))
is_weekend = dayofweek(col("new_date")).isin([1, 7])
Dilip_df = Dilip_df.withColumn(
    "new_date",
    when(is_weekend, date_add(col("new_date"), when(dayofweek(col("new_date")) == 1, 1).otherwise(2))).otherwise(col("new_date"))
)
Dilip_df.show()

+----------+----------+
|start_date|  new_date|
+----------+----------+
|2023-10-26|2023-10-31|
|2022-09-01|2022-09-06|
|2021-08-10|2021-08-16|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: your logic is directly adding the number of days and finally its checking if the obtained date is a weekend and if so its further adding to it and making the date as a weekday. 
But my question is different, i want to add or subtract to a given date without considering the weekends
**i.e.** Date - '29/12/2014', Days to Subtract - 9
Result - 17/12/2014
Result is calculated inclusive of 29/12/2014
Here 20,21,27,28 are Excluded as its a weekend

Comment: Let me try that update the solution.

Comment: days_to_add_or_subtract = -9

Dilip_df = Dilip_df.withColumn(
    "new_date",
    expr("""
        date_add(start_date, 
            CASE 
                WHEN {0} >= 0 THEN 
                    CAST({0} + (FLOOR({0} / 5.0) * 2) + 
                    CASE WHEN (MOD({0} + dayofweek(start_date), 7) > 5) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS INT)
                ELSE 
                    CAST({0} - (FLOOR({0} / 5.0) * 2) - 
                    CASE WHEN (MOD({0} - dayofweek(start_date), 7) < 1) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS INT)
            END
        )
    """.format(days_to_add_or_subtract))
)

Comment: Can you try this?